# ¿Cómo determinar el número de ciclos que utiliza mi programa en assembler?

Tags: ensamblador

Hola quería hacer unas consulta a cerca de lenguaje **assembler**, la primera es como hago para saber cuando tiempo demora en ejecutarse este programa (conozco la respuesta pero no entiendo como se llego a ella) :

```
movlw   .24 

movwf   cont2   

d2

movlw   .250

movwf   cont1       

d1

nop         

decfsz  cont1, f  

GOTO d1

decfsz  cont2, f

GOTO d2
```

La respuesta que se dio es primero 4*24 = 96 y luego 96*250 = "24000" como resultado final.

y la segunda duda es que no puedo armar un programa que haga lo siguiente:

*Preguntar si `num1>num2` si es mayor que se haga `NUM1 - NUM2` y se haga `resultado = port B`

si `NUM1 < NUM2` que se haga `NUM1 + NUM2` y el `resultado =portB.

y fin

Esas son mis 2 consultas si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria, es un lenguaje **assembler** de **PIC** sencillo pero no lo entiendo muy bien. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un calculo diferente:

- las dos primeras instrucciones se repiten solo dos veces.
- d1 se repite 250 veces, pero arrastra los 2 ciclos de inicialización de cont1.
- d2 se repite 24 veces.
- Hay que tener en cuenta que las instrucciones de comparación ocupan un ciclo cuando no saltan y dos cuando lo hacen. por lo que hay que agregarle los 24 a "goto d1" y uno 1 a "goto d2) que skipea solo una vez.

Esto me estaría dando: 2 + (252*24) + 24 + 1 =6.075 ciclos de maquinas.
Si usas un micro de 4MHZ y cada instrucción ocupa 4 ciclos de reloj (como el clásico 16F84), tendrías 1 microsegundo por cada instrucción.

```
        movlw   .24 
        movwf   cont2   // hasta aca 2 ciclos

    d2  movlw   .250
        movwf   cont1   // 2 ciclos en etiqueta d2 

    d1  nop         //1 ciclo
        decfsz  cont1, f  
        GOTO d1         // cont1 loopea de 250 y salta cuando es 0
// Aqui se agrega un ciclo mas cada vez que salta

        decfsz  cont2, f // cont2 loopea de 24 a 0 y salta cuando es 0 
        GOTO d2
// aquí se agrega otro ciclo de reloj
```

En cuanto a preguntar por num1>num2, si es mayor entonces hacer Num1-Num2 y el resultado pasarlo al PortB. Para saber si Num1>Num2, podrías poner a num1 en el registro de trabajo y luego restarle al registro de trabajo num2, almacenando el resultado en el registro de trabajo. Si el Bit de acarreo se pone en uno significa que efectivamente Num1>Num2, aparte de esto ya te queda en el registro de trabajo lo que deberías enviar al PortB cumplida la condición.

El codigo que te paso abajo loopea en verificar hasta que se cumpla la condición. Faltaría ingresar datos de alguna manera, pero al idea es como identificar si un registro es mayor a otro. De una manera similar deberías avanzar con la resolución de Num1> Num2.

```
verificar
    .
    .
    .
    Ingresar num1 y num2
    .
    .
    .

    movfw num1
    subwf num2,0 //guarda en W
    btfss STATUS,C //Verifica 1 en C
goto verificar
    movf w,PORTB //En W había quedado guardada el resultado de la resta
```